# Is it possible to install Freya on a laptop with mixed-mode EFI and eMMC flash?

Tags: system-installation, hardware, microsoft-windows, uefi, kernel

So I'm thinking about installing elementary on my ASUS X205TA netbook. It has several features that make it very difficult to get a working Linux installation going. Because of the lack of hardware support, getting *everything* working is probably impossible right now. However, people have had limited success with various flavours and releases of Ubuntu. (I don't have enough reputation to include the links, sorry.)

The main challenges:

**eMMC flash storage**

According to [this post](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/02/04/installing-ubuntu-on-baytrail-tablets-version-2/), the 3.19 kernel doesn't support it. This is inconvenient, because elementary 0.3.1, while based on 14.04, uses 3.19.

However, apparently eMMC is not an issue when running Debian Jessie and [kernel version 4.1](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA), which also fixes some of the X205TA's wifi and battery issues.

**32-bit UEFI and 64-bit processor**

This is annoying, but people have found workarounds involving custom .efi files, GRUB, and bootloaders like ELILO or rEFInd. Having installed Ubuntu on Macs before, I'm used to it.

**My questions:**

- Is it possible to use Freya with kernel version 4 and up?
- Is simply using the 32-bit version of Freya enough to avoid the mixed-mode EFI problem? Or will just using the newest kernel solve that problem?
- Or is this impossible, and I should just suck it up and get used to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The X205TA it's a really nice notebook. I think you should try this link [ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md), reading some info on the web looks like this can work.

Edit:
right now I'm runnin the live usb, the kernel is 3.19 the emmc and the wifi is not working, this is and maybe [debian reference instalation](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA) can help us (ñ_ñ).